# Systemd: service doesn't restart with WatchdogSec option set

Tags: qemu, systemd, watchdog

I'm trying to manager my vm with systemd. In case the qemu crashes, I want to implement watchdog for the service, following is the unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description=vm manager
After=network.target
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target poweroff.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/root/vm/vm-manager.sh start-vm
ExecStop=/root/vm/vm-manager.sh stop-vm
KillSignal=SIGCONT
PIDFile=/root/vm/run/pid
WatchdogSec=30s
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I didn't call sd_notify(0, "WATCHDOG=1") in my application, above is the background. I have two questions:

1. In my opinion, this service should be restarted after 30s, why it keeps running until I kill or stop it?
2. When I kill qemu manually(I take qemu process as the main process), the service restart immediately, without waiting.

Besides the two questions, if there's anything wrong or suggestion about the unit file, please raise it freely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
  NotifyAccess=1
```

if you dont, systemd will not enable the watchdog feature for your service.

The man page for systemd.service says:

**WatchdogSec=**
    *If this option is used, NotifyAccess= (see below) should be set to open access to the notification socket provided by systemd. If NotifyAccess= is not set, it will be implicitly set to main. Defaults to 0, which disables this feature. The service can check whether the service manager expects watchdog keep-alive notifications. See sd_watchdog_enabled(3) for details. sd_event_set_watchdog(3) may be used to enable automatic watchdog notification support.*